# how to get specific values in a list of object values in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java! Could any one tell me how I can get the specific values in the list of objects?

Here is my code:

```
end = CourseLocalServiceUtil.getCoursesCount();

List<Course> c = CourseLocalServiceUtil.getCourses(0, end);
```

The c object contains a list of course objects. I want to display only particular column values of all course objects.

I need to get `c.getCourseName()` in all the course objects. Could any one help me?

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc for the `List` class? Do you know about `for` loops?

Comment: little bit knowledge i have...i dnt know how to get perticular value from the whole list of same objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a method that helps you to convert a `List<A>` to a `List<B>` if you provide the `Function<A,B>` which converts A to B.

Your input is a `List<Course>`. The output you want is a `List<String>`. Here is an example :

```
Collection<String> col = Collections2.transform(inputCol, new Function<Course, String>() {
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public String apply(@Nullable Course input) {
    //Here, specify how to extract the value you want from the Course.
    return input.getName();
  }
});
```

Comment: it showing error at Function.

Comment: There were some problems with the variables names. I edited. But provided that you have included the library Guava, you should not have error on `Function`. Check that the import is `import com.google.common.base.Function;`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using some of the built-in implementations of the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface.

Like, for instance, [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), in which the *courseName* will be a **key** and the `Counse` will be a corresponding **value**.

This approach will allow you get a specific element with complexity of *O(1)*. Otherwise, if you will strongly prefer using `List`, you will have to search for a specific object with some loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for each loop as shown below

```
   for(Course course : c)
    {

       System.out.println(c.getCourseName() + "  " + c.getCourseID() + ...so on)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to override the `toString()` method of an `java.lang.Object` class into you'r 
'Course' class as follows.

```
public class Course {

    private String column1;
    private String column2;
    //dont want to show the value of this column.
    private double fees;

    public Course(String column1, String column2, double fees) {
        super();
        this.column1 = column1;
        this.column2 = column2;
        this.fees = fees;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course [column1=" + column1 + ", column2=" + column2 + "]";
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course course = new Course("abc","xyz",1000.00);
        System.out.println(course);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Course Class:

```
public class Course {

   //declaration of properties
   private String courseName;
   ....other property declaration    


  //setter/getter methods for properties as applicable...         


  /*
  override toString. This will be used when you use object.toString(). 
  E.g. in Course c=new Course(), and you print as System.out.println(c), 
  it will call to toString() and will be printed the return value. 
  */

   @Override
   public String toString() {
        return "\n"+courseName;
    }  

}
```

Your code to print the list...

```
end = CourseLocalServiceUtil.getCoursesCount();

List<Course> c = CourseLocalServiceUtil.getCourses(0, end);
System.out.println(c);
```

You can also store all the courses in a String as:

```
String allCourse = c.toString();
System.out.println("List of courses = "+allCourse);
```

Note: toString() is a method that is used across any objects and inherited from Object class. You can also overried and implement it to customize your toString() as per your own logic on any of the objects say Employee, Course etc.

You can see the toString() that is implemented in the ArrayList or LinkedList for a better idea.

Comment: i want only course name....!

Comment: sudheer, it will print only the course name. But do you need to use the course name in some other way apart from println()? Please mention.

Comment: would you be more specific of your requirement if the above solution is not well suited for your question?

Comment: no.. in Course class i have cname cdescription are string types.i only need to get cname..

Comment: well, in toString(), you can just change the line as:
return "\n"+cname;
or
return "\n"+getcname();

I use "\n" just to separater and print each course in a new line when you print the list.

Comment: in jsp iam using jquey json and ajax for getting information for available cnames i need to send cname only...

Comment: what should be the json format for your course which you use in jsp?

Comment: JsonObject.put("cname",c.getCname());

Comment: JsonObject.put("cname",c.getCname());
click(function() {
      var nameVal = jQuery("#cname").val();
       jQuery.ajax({
                url :'<%=resourceURL%>',           
                data: {pid:nameVal},
                type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
             success: function(data) {             
                   $("#a").html(data);

document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML="<font color=green>cname:"+data["cname"];

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Course> c= CourseLocalServiceUtil.findCourse(cname);

       System.out.println(c);
       ArrayList al =new ArrayList(c);
       String cname1=c.get(0).getCname();   
       System.out.println(cname1);
```

IT WORKS FOR SINGLE COURSE OBJECT